# How to set `__class__.__name__` as class attribute?

Tags: python

I need to get class name from class:

```py
class Cls:
    notation = None

    def __init__(self):
        notation = self.__class__.__name__
```

`print(Cls.notation)` prints `None` but I need `'Cls'`

How to fix it or how to define class attribute which returns a name of class?

Comment: Why not just use `Cls.__name__`?

Comment: @Chris, that's not enough obvious to me. I want to create an interface

Comment: [That _is_ the Python interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=class%20__name__#definition.__name__).

Comment: Your approach of using `__init__` will not work before the first instance of the class was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to a local variable, not the class attribute:

```
def __init__(self):
    Cls.notation = self.__class__.__name__
```

Note that `self.__class__` isn't necessarily `Cls`, if there is a subclass of `Cls` involved. You might want to use

```
def __init__(self):
    type(self).notation = self.__class__.__name__
```

depending on your use case.

Assigning to `self.notation` won't work, because that creates an instance attribute that shadows the class attribute.

If you want `Cls.notation == "Cls"` immediately after the class is defined, you may as well just hard-code it:

```
class Cls:
    notation = "Cls"
```

or

```
class Cls:
    pass

Cls.notation = Cls.__name__
```

though you can also write

```
class Cls:
    notation = __qualname__
```

to set its value based on the name used in the first line of the statement, though `__qualname__` takes into account nesting as well:

```
class Cls1:
    class Cls2:
        notation = __qualname__  # "Cls1.Cls2", not "Cls2"
```

Comment: This will not create the class attribute until an instance is created.

Comment: Well, the class attribute is *created* when the class is defined. It's true, though, that *modifying* the attribute's value only happens when an instance is created.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover setting the value at class definition time.

Comment: ```Cls.notation = self.__class__.__name__``` and ```type(self).notation = self.__class__.__name__``` don't work for ```python  3.8.0``` -- still returns ```None``` :( I'll check another options

Comment: @PavelAntspovich, your best option is just to use the `__name__` (or `__qualname__` if that's what you're actually after) that Python already provides. This will be much less confusing for anybody else reading the code. You might not _like_ it, but it's idiomatic.

Comment: @PavelAntspovich As already mentioned, `__init__` isn't run until you create an *instance* of the class; it's not called automatically when you *define* the class.